# Converting pandas column types to string to save in h5py file still shows an error for object type

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, h5py

I have a pandas DataFrame of the following form

| *TITLE* | *CONTEXT* |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 |
| A2 | B2 |

When I list the dtypes of the columns, it displays the following with `table_1.dtypes`

```
TITLE                           object
CONTEXT                         object
dtype: object
```

After converting the columns types to string and with the following:

```
TITLE                           string
CONTEXT                         string
dtype: object
```

I still see the dtype being listed at the end as *object*. When I try to save it in a h5py file, it throws me the following error

```
TypeError: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent
```

Anybody has suggestions on how to deal with this issue when the columns are string types, yet h5py throws the error.

Comment: I got it to work without the object to string conversion with this - pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/…

Answer (score 0):

How are you converting them to `str`? Try this `df.astype({'col_name": str})`

Comment: I used a for loop - `for col in table_1.columns: table_1[col] = table_1[col].astype('string')`

Comment: Also, pandas consider str as object, if you print df.dtypes

Comment: Try str instead of string

Comment: Using `str` does not change the column dtype with the above loop.

Comment: As far as I can tell pandas consider string as object that is why object is displayed when you print dtypes

Comment: So that means, there isn't a way to store these dataframes with string columns in h5py files?

Comment: No, I think the above statement should execute with the object type, if not. I will try something else.

Comment: Dyd you run this statement: df.to_hdf('test.h5','df',mode='w',format='table',data_columns=True)

Comment: When I execute that statement, it gives me a different error: `AttributeError: 'StringDtype' object has no attribute 'itemsize'`
`

Comment: Ok, I got it to work without the conversion with this - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#hdf5-pytables.